# What's wrong with this Event Handler?

Tags: jquery, carousel, owl-carousel

I'm using [Owl Carousel](http://www.owlcarousel.owlgraphic.com/) on a project.
Code:

```
$("#my-rotator").owlCarousel({
    items: 7,
    center: false,
    loop: false,
    autoplayTimeout: 1500,
    autoplay: false,
    autoplayHoverPause: true,
    mouseDrag: true,
    onDragged: callback
});

function callback(event) {
    var element = event.target; 
    var items = event.item.count;
    var item = event.item.index;
    console.log(items);
    console.log(item);
}
```

when I drag the items, console says `TypeError: event is undefined` on `var element = event.target;`

I follow the [Documentation](http://www.owlcarousel.owlgraphic.com/docs/api-events.html), but I don't see where I'm wrong.

Comment: Owl 2 is pretty new yet. Could be a bug. Maybe try `on('dragged.owl.carousel', function(e)`.

Comment: It works! If you place the answer, you will get +1 ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure why your approach isn't working. It seems like it should be. In my experience the docs for Owl Carousel 2 are incomplete and perhaps incorrect.

Maybe try this alternative technique:

```
$('#myElement').on('dragged.owl.carousel', function(e) {
    ...
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes -

```html
$('#myElement').on('dragged.owl.carousel', function(e) {...});
```

But you must to know that - this code must be before carousel initialization ($('selector').owlCarousel();) code - after that it doesn't work.